# Using googleAnalyticsR, how to track sessions on a specific campaign?

Tags: r, google-analytics

```
ga_data <- google_analytics(viewId = view_id, date_range = c(start_date, end_date), 
                            metrics = "sessions", dimensions = "Source", 
                            order = order_sessions_desc, max = -1)
```

I want to use the sources within the campaign and the number of sessions as a metric. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `meta` to see all the allowed metrics and dimensions

```r
library(googleAnalyticsR)
meta
```

When you do that you can see that you need `ga:campaign` e.g.

```r
ga_data <- google_analytics(viewId = view_id, date_range = c(start_date, end_date), 
                            metrics = "sessions", dimensions = "campaign", 
                            order = order_sessions_desc, max = -1)
```

If you want to filter to a specific campaign, you need a dimension filter:

```r
campaign_filter <- dim_filter(dimension="campaign",
                              operator="EXACT",
                              expressions="your_campaign_name")

my_filter_clause <- filter_clause_ga4(list(campaign_filter))

ga_data <- google_analytics(viewId = view_id, 
                            date_range = c(start_date, end_date), 
                            metrics = "sessions", 
                            dimensions = "campaign", 
                            dim_filter = my_filter_clause,
                            max = -1)
```

You can read more on [GA filters on the website](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/v4.html#filters).